# Vue2 getting image src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, filereader

### I have a function that gets images from an array

```
onFileChange(e) {
            let files = e.target.files;
            for (let file in files) {
                this.files.push(URL.createObjectURL(files[file]));
                if (files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
                    console.log(files[file]);
                }
}
```

### Which is triggered by this element:

```
<input multiple type="file" @change="onFileChange($event)"/>
```

### My data object for this component is:

```
data() {
        return {
            files: [],
            url: null,
            uploadedFiles: []
}
```

### When I render I get this error:

> app.js:1920 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

I am actually getting the file array. but with this error, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why this error occured yet i've found a workaround by switch from for/in to a regular "boring" for.

```
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i],
                    src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
                this.files.push(src);
                }
```

If there'll be an answer that would explain the error, ill vote it as the answer, this this is the best solve found by now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from this line `this.files.push(URL.createObjectURL(files[file]));`

It should be `this.files.push(window.URL.createObjectURL(files[file]));` in case of `{}.toString.apply(files[file]) === '[object Blob]'`

Otherwise,

```
const binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(files[file]);
window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))
```

Ref: [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL'](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/949#issuecomment-268757472)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with `for` and `for...in`, it's with `window.URL`.
After you used this:

```
(window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL
```

Instead of this (`URL` => `window.URL`):

```
URL.createObjectURL
```

It worked for you, it's a browser compatibility issue.